# creating custom message body in Swift Mailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am using PHP Swift Mailer to send Mail to my user, whose email and name are stored in my database, I am able to send them mail using SwiftMailer's batchSend() method. but i want to send every mail body to be specific to each user like example..
if i have 3 user  with name and email(user1=> user1@domain.com, user2=> user2@domain.com, user3=> user3@domain.com), in body i want 
 `hello, user_name.  the message. thank you, user_name` 
 
how can this be done, is there any Plugin or method available for composing custom message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey i got the solution, it was given in the Swift Mailer documentation, in Plugin Section. 
We can do this by using the Decorator Plugin of Swift Mailer. Before asking the question i should have read the documentation completely..